# document is undefined in Google URL harvester

Tags: javascript, url

I have code taken from Google to harvest URLs from Google. I saved it as filename.js. When I run the file it showed "'document' is undefined". The part of the code which is showing problem is

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Google URL Harvester
// @namespace      http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/42998
// @description    Harvests URLs from a Google Search
// @include        http://www.google.co.uk/
// @include        http://www.google.com/
// ==/UserScript==

var btn_container;
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if (inputs[i].name == "btnG")
        btn_container = inputs[i].parentNode;
}

function find_next_link(html) {
    var url = html.match(/(<a href="[^"]+">)\s*<span[^>]+style="[^"]*background-position:\s?-76px\s/);
    if (url == null)
        return false;

    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = url[1];
    return div.firstChild.href;
}

function harvest(query_url, callback) {
    ajax(query_url, function(e){
        var als = e.match(/<a[^>]+class=l[^>]*>/g);
        for (var i = 0; i < als.length; i++) {
            urls.push(als[i].match(/href="([^"]+)"/)[1]);
        }
        var next_url = find_next_link(e);
        if (next_url)
            harvest(next_url, callback);
        else
            callback();
    });
}

function ajax(url, callback) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
            callback(req.responseText);
        }
    }
    req.open("GET", url, true);
    req.send("");
}

var new_button = document.createElement("input");
new_button.type = "button";
new_button.value = "Harvest URLs";
new_button.setAttribute("onsubmit", "return false;");
btn_container.appendChild(new_button);
var urls = [];
new_button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    var query_url = unsafeWindow.document.forms[0].action + "?num=100&q="+escape(unsafeWindow.document.forms[0].q.value);
    document.body.innerHTML = "<img src='http://oneworldwebsites.com/images/wheel%20throbber.gif' />";
    harvest(query_url, function() {
        document.body.innerHTML = urls.join("<br/>");
    });
},false);
```

Here I have not defined document(if it is necessary). Can anybody please rectify the error in this code. Operating system is Windows 7.

I am saving this document to my desktop as harv.js and running it. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: i prefer to use jQuery `$(document).ready(function() {`
 `console.log($('input[name="btng"]').parent())`
`})`

Comment: @narayanpatra, what u exactly want to do???

Comment: What browser are you using?  Can you shed some light on what the rest of the document looks like ?

Comment: @dolanI am using mozilla firefox. @diEcho : I want to harvest URLs from google searches. I am posting entire code. Kindly analyze.

Comment: Are you wrapping the text in a script-tag?  <script type="text/javascript"> </script> (or defining in a .js file -- please post the include statement if so)

Comment: I am saving it as js file and running it. I have posted the entire code. There are no include statement.

Comment: How are you running it?  I'm used to including JS files on HTML pages.. maybe I'm missing something

Comment: @dolan: This is an userscript, included with a Browser Add-on like 'Greasemonkey'

Comment: Can anybody explain me entire procedure please?

Comment: You are going to want to learn how to use user scripts in browsers first. For Firefox follow this tutorial.

http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/get_started_with_greasemonkey/

Comment: @jairaj. I learned about greasemonkey. But while installing the script it is showing the same error again. May be there is problem in the code. Can anybody debug this for me please?

Comment: If you figured it out, please post what you came up with as an answer and accept it so people in the future can know what to do.

Comment: I got the code from userscripts.org. I was trying to add it manually to mozilla but later I found the install button in the userscripts.org neat to that script. I directly installed it. I don't know yet what is the exact reason behind this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Google like most websites updates their structure over time.

```
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if (inputs[i].name == "btnG")
        btn_container = inputs[i].parentNode;
}
```

Needs to become

```
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if (inputs[i].name == "btnK") //<<------G to K
        btn_container = inputs[i].parentNode;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can just guess that the error is thrown because you try to access the "input" element, before creating it later. Moreover you shouldn't use a html element as a identifier in JavaScript. You could also use Firebug to pinpoint the error.